# Automatically install printers shared on Windows Domain

Tags: 14.04, printing, samba

All of the resources I can find provide detailed instructions for sharing Linux printers with Windows over SAMBA.

I would like to do the opposite.

I currently have CUPS configured so that it can add and print to printers shared from a Windows print server.

The problem is that I must manually configure the printer and select which driver it uses.

Is there any "out of the box" way to automatically determine the appropriate driver and/or autoconfigure a printer accessed via samba?  If there are command line approaches I am comfortable wrapping them up in a script if need be.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd love to see something like this. It's really annoying having to add all of my school's 20+ printers (separate buildings).

Answer (score 0):

This is the trick:

- Add a `print$` share in `smb.conf` if it doesn't already exist
- Move the Windows drivers into `/usr/share/cups/drv`
- Run `cupsaddsmb -H localhost -U root -a -v`

You can find more info at:

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/cupsaddsmb.8.html
- http://www.geekyprojects.com/ubuntu/getting-windows-printer-drivers-from-cups/